# ¿Cómo puedo hacer un update en sql usando un split?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo una tabla que se llama `TB_ProductComposition` y tiene los campos :

``` idProductcomposition``quantity``idMaterial``idProduct``idUser``dateAdd ```

https://ibb.co/gjD2Fx9 esta url es una imagen de la tabla

inserto los datos de la siguiente manera :

```
  declare @Material table(numero int not null identity(1, 1), idMaterial int);
                     declare @Quantity table(numero int not null identity(1, 1), quantity int);

                     insert into @Material (idMaterial) select value from string_split(@pidMaterial, ',');
                     insert into @Quantity (quantity) select value from string_split(@pQuantity, ',');
            
                     insert into [TB_ProductComposition] (quantity, idMaterial, idProduct, idUser)
                     select  m.idMaterial,cast(q.quantity as decimal(18,2)),@pidProduct,@pidUser
                     from @Material m
                     inner join @Quantity q on q.numero = m.numero

                     insert into [TB_ProductCities]
                                  ([idProduct]
                                  ,[idCity])

                                select [value] = @vidProduct , [value]
                                from string_split(@pidCitys,',')
```

y necesito actualizar todos registro que inserte anterior mente mediante el id del producto, ya que en el lugar donde los voy a actualizar muestro todos los registro relacionados a un idProduct

estoy intentado algo así :

```
   declare @Material table(numero int not null identity(1, 1), idMaterial int);
                     declare @Quantity table(numero int not null identity(1, 1), quantity int);

                     insert into @Material (idMaterial) select value from string_split(@pidMaterial, ',');
                     insert into @Quantity (quantity) select value from string_split(@pQuantity, ',');
            
                     UPDATE [TB_ProductComposition] 
                     SET
                      quantity = cast(q.quantity as decimal(18,2))
                     ,idMaterial = m.idMaterial
                     from @Material m
                     inner join @Quantity q on q.numero = m.numero
                     WHERE idProduct = @pidProduct
```

Comment: En base a qué regla debes actualizar. Es decir, vamos a cambiar los productos de las ciudades, o vamos a cambiar las ciudades de los productos? Pregunto, porque más que la sintaxis, el problema no está bien definido y no se puede escribir una solución para algo que no se entiende del todo.

Comment: @jachguate los dos campos, yo guardo el id en un tabla del split que se acabo de crear para tener el id del split pero aun no encuentro la forma correcta de hacerlo ya que de la forma que me indica samuel se inserta solo el primer valor del arreglo en todos en todos los campos

Comment: Creo que quizás no has entendido como funciona la cláusula `update` en SQL. Dejemos de pensar por un momento en varios registros y enfoquémonos en el primer par. Tienes `City = 4` y `Product = 1`, y en la tabla tienes potencialmente miles de registros. ¿A cuál registro de todos esos le quieres poner estos valores?

Comment: Esto, asumiendo, para comenzar, que quieres actualizar esta información a un único registro de todos esos que pueden haber en la base de datos. Puede que haya un solo registro cuya ciudad sea 4 y quieras tomar ese registro y actualizar product para que sea 1. Puede ser que haya un único registro cuyo Product sea 1 y quieras actualizar ese registro para que ahora City sea 4. Puede que, al momento de actualizar, haya cientos de registros con Product igual a 1 y otros cientos (no necesariamente los mismos) con City = 4. A cuales de estos quieres _tocar_ en la actualización?

Comment: Si logro explicarme, verás que el primer problema no es de sintaxis de SQL, sino de explicar bien qué es lo que quieres lograr, ya que sin entenderlo bien, no hay manera de tener la certeza de escribir una sentencia SQL que lo cumpla.

Comment: @jachguate entonces voy a formularte la pregunta de nuevo para que la entiendas mejor

Comment: Ok, déjame un comentario cuando hayas terminado la edición, para que re-visite la pregunta y vea si me aclaro. Un saludo.

Comment: @jachguate listo, no se si ya me entiendas mejor ?

Comment: Podrías incluir la imagen directamente en la pregunta, no como un vínculo, pero ya que son datos, mejor aún, publicar los datos como texto plano como parte de tu pregunta. Por otro lado, no tendrías ningún problema de estos si junto a materiales y cantidades te envían  los ID's de los registros en la BD, que podrían venir en una lista, igual, para relacionar por su posición. Se puede hacer de otras maneras, pero considero que son complicaciones innecesarias.

Comment: @jachguate pero me la forma que lo estoy intentado para actualizar me queda me queda solo el primer dato en todos los campo de la columna es decir si me envían var ='2,3,4,5,6' solo toma el primer valor para todos es ósea 2, sabes por que es ?

Comment: Si, pero me parece irrelevante hasta no resolver los temas de fondo.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124403/discussion-between-jachguate-and-brayan-romero).

Answer (score 1):

Puedes guardar tu resultado de tu Split en una tabla, créate una tabla dinámica  después de eso haces un recorrido de esa tabla y obtienes el  id y lo actualizas

```
DECLARE @ini as int = 1
SELECT @fin = COUNT(*) FROM TABLA_GENRADA

WHILE @fin > @ini 
BEGIN
    declare @nro as int = 0 ;
    select @nro = id from  TABLA_GENRADA
    
    update TABLA_A_ACTUALIZAR set CAMPO_1 = '....' where id = @nro  
END
```

Comment: esos datos ya los insertos en una tabla pero lo que necesito es que se actualicen todos los campos que vienen en el arreglo de las dos variables  donde el el valor idProductCities = 2 que es la llave primaria y el  autoincremental de la tabla

Comment: supongamos que tu arreglo viene {1 , 2 3} entonces eso agrega en una tabla temporal  créala con 2 campos  el id autoincremento y el id de tu array  entonces cuando ingrese al while tu obtendrás el id 1  entonces haces un where y obtienes el id de tu array , ya con ese id puedes actualizar

Comment: Samuel, quité el snippet, ya que este se utiliza solamente cuando se publican preguntas/respuestas de HTML/CSS/Javascript y sirve para que se pueda ejecutar un [mcve] directamente en el navegador.